# node.js can read only *js - files?

Tags: node.js

Example :

```
    var directory='C:/node/my_modules/'
    var http = require("http");
    var url = require("url");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var fn = function(request, response) {

      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

      fs.readFile(directory+'first.js','utf8',function(err,data){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
                console.log('cant openfile')
            }
        console.log(data)
      })

      response.end('_testcb("param")');
    }


    function start(){
    http.createServer(fn).listen(1337);
    console.log('start Server');
    }

exports.start = start;
```

This example works ....In console i see data from file .

But when fs.readFile(directory+'my.txt' then error :

**ENOENT, "no such file or directory"**

How to get the contents of the my.txt file

**my.txt is in the same directory as first.js**

Comment: readFile should be able to read any file. Are you sure my.txt is there in the same directory as first.js?

Comment: Your error message is "no such file or directory"... That's the problem. Why do you think this has to do with only being able to read js files?

Comment: my.txt is in the same directory as first.js

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong. .. I created a file my.txt.txt

Comment: Can you please delete this question. Dont need to be indexed..